# WordPress : adding read more link for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm  fetching data from  custom post type  Products using  `product-template.php` like this

```
   <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <h1>Our Products</h1>
        <?php
         $args=array('post_type' => 'products');
         $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
         while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()?>
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
             <h1><?php echo the_title();?></h1>
             <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'innerimages') );?>
         </div>

     <?php                                
        endwhile;
     ?>
   </div>
```

now what i want to do is title should be clickable and once clicked on next page i should be able to get all the details about clicked product how do i do this ? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
         <h1><a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink() ?>"><?php echo the_title();?></a></h1>
         <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'innerimages') );?>
     </div>
```

If it doesn't work try :

```
     <h1><a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($post->ID) ?>"><?php echo the_title();?></a></h1>
```

Comment: so where should i redirect to should  i do a new page template for priting the content   ?

Comment: With this method you will link to single page of the custom post type - make a file in your theme "single-{post_type}.php" and the custom posts will use that template. If you want you can copy and paste the code from "single.php" file to the new one  "single-{post_type}.php"  where {post_type} you should replace with the name of your custom post type.

Comment: `echo the_title()`? that doesn't seem right. `echo get_post_permalink()` why not just `the_permalink()`?

Comment: so for products i shall create a file single-product.php and will copy  content from single.php and then  do i need to add anything else to that like the_content() ?

Comment: Yes you are right. Sikander remove echo before the_title()

Comment: In single.php i think you have the_title and the_content so in single-product.php you will have it too when you paste the code. But be sure that "product" is the name of your custom post type when registering it.

Comment: YES got it thank you very much.hope it will work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

U have to use a single page for your custom post type.

single-your_custom_post_type.php

In your case : "single-products.php".
Then add the loop

You can create an archive page that list all your custom post type

archive-your_custom_post_type.php (archive-products.php)
And use the same loop

```
<div class="site-content">
    <?php
        if ( have_posts() )
        {
            while ( have_posts() )
            {
                the_post();
                the_title();
                the_content();
            }
        }

    ?>
</div>
```

In your template page add after the thumbnail a permalink.

```
echo "<a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>Read more</a>";
```

ps: `the_title()` display the title, you don't need to echoes it. If you want to echo, then use `echo get_the_title();`

I hope that help you.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($post->ID) ?>">READ MORE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

with the **get_permalink** you can get the permalink for a post, [for details see the wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

Comment: so where should i redirect to should i do a new page template for priting the content

Comment: the `get_permalink` command returns the full url for a post, so the get_permalink will return "http://yoursite.com/your-post-type/your-post-name", so you can use `<a href="<?= get_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>`